# Unable to change grant privileges for another user from root user

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, privileges, user-accounts, sql-grant

I'm logged in as root user to an Amazon RDS MySql 5.7 database from MySql workbench.

I've added a user via the following command:

```
CREATE USER 'my_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
```

I'm trying to grant access to the user via this command:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'my_user'@'%'
```

However, this returns the error:

```
Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

I'm not sure if this should work if the user already exists, so based in this post:

```
https://serverfault.com/questions/115950/how-do-i-change-the-privileges-for-mysql-user-that-is-already-created
```

I also tried this command:

```
revoke all privileges on *.* from 'my_user'@'%'
```

However, I receive the same result. I also had the same problem when I tried creating the user with the GRANT command.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but I think the root user might be restricted on RDS. When I did a native install of mysql, the command worked.

Answer (score 0):

None other than `RDS` user can't have the `root user` privileges.